# Aligning a Table and a diagram in the same line

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, diagrams

I wish to align a table and a diagram vertically on a line. Here is my code:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l||c|r}
              & a & b \\
\hline
$q_0           & q_1 & q_0$ \\
$q_1           & q_1 & q_2$ \\
$q_2           & q_2 & q_2$
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  node {a} (q_1)
          edge  [loop above] node {b} ()
    (q_1) edge  node  {b} (q_2)
          edge [loop above] node {a} ()
    (q_2) edge [loop below] node {a,b} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}
```

Currently, my output is as follows:

[image]

1. How do I get the table and diagram to be aligned vertically?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Please post a complete Minimum Working Example. That code gives people no real idea what you are doing. How much more of the picture is there, for example? That might well affect the alignment! Moreover, you don't say *how* you want them aligned - aligned on the baseline? aligned at the top? centred vertically with respect to each other? left aligned horizontally?

Comment: First, remove the blank line between the tabular and tikzpicture (new paragraph).  You might want to throw in an \hfil or two for spacing.  Oh, you might need a \raisebox or \parbox, since tabulars align to the top and tikzpictures to the bottom (IIRC).

Comment: \begin{tabular}[b] works, but \parbox[c]{1in}{\centering for the tikzpicture works better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution based on    \savebox and     \raisebox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\newsavebox{\boxA}
\newsavebox{\boxB}
\newlength{\lenA}
\newlength{\lenB}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\boxA}
{\begin{tabular}[c]{l||c|r}
              & a & b \\
\hline
$q_0$           & $q_1$ & $q_0$ \\
$q_1$           & $q_1$ & $q_2$ \\
$q_2$           & $q_2$ & $q_2$
\end{tabular}}
\settoheight{\lenA}{\usebox{\boxA}}

\savebox{\boxB}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  node {a} (q_1)
          edge  [loop above] node {b} ()
    (q_1) edge  node  {b} (q_2)
          edge [loop above] node {a} ()
    (q_2) edge [loop below] node {a,b} ();
\end{tikzpicture}}
\settoheight{\lenB}{\usebox{\boxB}}

\noindent
Align tops:

\noindent
\hfil\raisebox{-\lenA}{\usebox{\boxA}}
\hfil\raisebox{-\lenB}{\usebox{\boxB}}

\noindent
Align centers:

\noindent
\hfil\usebox{\boxA}
\hfil\raisebox{-0.5\lenB}{\usebox{\boxB}}

\noindent
Align bottoms:

\noindent
\hfil\raisebox{\lenA}{\usebox{\boxA}}
\hfil\usebox{\boxB}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

For some strange reason,    \lenA is half the size expected.  I guess    \settoheight measures the distance from the top to the baseline rather than the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `minipage` environment with `option [t,c,b]{width of choice}` for the alignment on top, center and bottom respectivlely.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{l||c|r}
              & a & b \\\hline
$q_0$           &$ q_1$ & $q_0$ \\
$q_1$           & $q_1$ & $q_2$ \\
$q_2$           & $q_2$ & $q_2$
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\vsapce{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  node {a} (q_1)
          edge  [loop above] node {b} ()
    (q_1) edge  node  {b} (q_2)
          edge [loop above] node {a} ()
    (q_2) edge [loop below] node {a,b} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Also a `tabular` environment with `array` package is a possible solution

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,array}                % require array package here
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}
\begin{tabular}{l||c|r}
                & a & b \\\hline
$q_0$           &$ q_1$ & $q_0$ \\
$q_1$           & $q_1$ & $q_2$ \\
$q_2$           & $q_2$ & $q_2$
\end{tabular}   &
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  node {a} (q_1)
          edge  [loop above] node {b} ()
    (q_1) edge  node  {b} (q_2)
          edge [loop above] node {a} ()
    (q_2) edge [loop below] node {a,b} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

\end{document}
```